# How to convert Image to binary and store it in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, reporting-services

I have image locally and I need to convert them to binary form and store them in my SQL Server database, and should be able to access them from a SSRS report.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Image to binary bytes uploaded using `File Upload` like

```
(byte[])fileuploader.FileBytes
```

and send it as a parameter to the Insert Command or Stored Procedure in `SQL Server`

In your `SSRS` report do the following steps

1. Insert a Image in your report
2. Right click on the Image and select `Image Properties`
3. In the `Image Properties` window select the `select image source as:` `Database`

---

**Addition**

Follow the below Steps for storing and retrieving the Logo Image of the Client from the Database and showing it in `SSRS` report

1.Convert the Logo Image of the Client uploaded using `File Upload` Control into bytes like

```
(byte[])fileuploader.FileBytes
```

2.Pass it on as a parameter to the Insert Command or the Stored Procedure with other details of the Client to a Table like

```
Create Table Client_Details
{
 PK_ClientID int Identity(1,1),
 Client_Name Varchar(250),
 Client_Address Varchar(750),
 Client_Logo Varbinary(max),
 Last_insDate datetime
}
```

3. Retrieve the `PK_Clientid` from the `Client_Details` Table  based on the Client who login and store it in the `Session` Variable and pass that `Session["PK_Clientid"]` as `Clientid` parameter to the `SSRS` report to retrieve the client details as well as the Logo image of the client and Show it in the Report as I mentioned above

Comment: I should be able to get a logo of client based on the client i login to. I am not suppose to add image in rdl file.

Comment: This is the same scenario which we were doing in our project Add the Logo Image of the Client in the Database as Bytes with other details of the client with `PK_CLIENTID` and reterive the Logo image of the Client by passing the `PK_CLIENTID` to your `SSRS` report as parameter the `PK_CLIENTID` is based on the client logged in our website dont forget the `PK_CLIENTID` in your DB Table its very important to fetch the Information

Answer (score 0):

Initially when Posting Image Make sure that form is in enctype="multipart/form-data".
then catch file and convert it to byte[] as shown below in your service and then insert it to SQLSERVER

```
var FileStream=Request.Files;
byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[FileStream[0].InputStream.Length];
FileStream[0].InputStream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
```

while retreiving you again need to convert it to base64 string and pass to image tag

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">


<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,StringHere" >
```